# Matlab:figure error

Tags: matlab-figure

I'm having a problem with set function in MatLab gui I'm getting this error :

> Invalid handle object.

there is my code:

```
[value index] = min( CostFunction(params, ...
                               input_layer_size, ...
                               hidden_layer_size, ...
                               num_labels, ...
                               X, y, lambda));

set(handles.cfwoText,????,value);
```

Value returned from [value index]is type double ex:1.4563e-011,and I want to show it on EditText called cfwoText,but i dont know what type should I write in ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple google search will provide an answer.
In addition, in GUIDE you can write click your Edit Text and choose Property Inspector. You will see all the properties.
Having said that, what you are looking for is

```
set(handles.cfwoText,'String',num2str(value));
```

Note that `num2str` is required since `value` is double and the text is string.